# Include space in mysql like search

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I am having problem in using mysql like keyword in certain condition. My requirement goes like this.
First, when i search for `'ABC'`, the result should find `ABC` and `ABCdef` but not  `xyzABCdef`  or `xyzABC`. It seems simple at first to use `ABC%`. but in condition when i search for `'heart%'`, it doesnot return row that have `'liver heart'` because it returns only row that have `heart` at the beginning of the string.Then i tried using `% heart%`.This returned row having `'liver heart'` but not those rows that have heart at the beginning of string. I am kind of stuck here..so guys help me.

**EDIT**
With your help guys i came with the following solution but still its giving me some problem.

```
    SELECT q.question_id, q.question, q.date,p.fname,p.lname,p.phys_id,
p.pic_path  
            FROM questions q JOIN physiciansprofile p ON p.phys_id=q.phys_id   
         WHERE  q.question  LIKE 'heart%' OR question LIKE '% heart%' 
            AND q.question LIKE 'liver%' OR q.question LIKE '% liver%' 
    ORDER BY q.date DESC LIMIT 0,10;
```

But this query return `heart failure` and `symptoms liver` as well.Is there any solution for this. I need to get result containing both `heart` and `liver` and also must satisfy condition as stated before. Is there any to solve this

Comment: can you post your whole code?

Answer (score 6):

'% heart%' doesn't work because you are asking for anything, plus space, plus heart, plus anything.

Try something like:

```
like 'heart%' OR like '% heart%'
```

Answer (score 3):

I just saw this old unsolved request. As someone may have the same question, I'll post the answer in spite of the request's age.

```
WHERE q.question LIKE 'heart%' OR question LIKE '% heart%' 
AND q.question LIKE 'liver%' OR q.question LIKE '% liver%'
```

translates to

```
WHERE q.question LIKE 'heart%' 
OR (question LIKE '% heart%' AND q.question LIKE 'liver%')
OR q.question LIKE '% liver%'
```

because AND has precedence over OR.

So one must use parentheses here. This is often the case when mixing AND and OR and it's good habit to *always* do so:

```
WHERE (q.question LIKE 'heart%' OR question LIKE '% heart%')
AND (q.question LIKE 'liver%' OR q.question LIKE '% liver%')
```

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
WHERE foo LIKE '% heart%' OR foo LIKE 'heart%'
```

Comment: using %heart% would match theart as well.So that cant be used

Comment: pardon sir? what exactly do you mean?

Comment: i mean %heart% would match xyzheart as well. I mean searching should be reasonable.If user enter hea than result should include heart but not theatre and so on.So using %s% is not correct in my case.

Comment: so your desired output is `liver heart` `heart` and `heart failure`?

Comment: i need result containing both heart and liver not only heart or liver.It must be and

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32137/discussion-between-ntstha-and-aw)

Comment: so all the results that has a liver and a heart in the word?