# SQL query to retrieve exactly matching record with or without LIKE

Tags: mysql, performance, drupal-7

From a rest API URL, I'm receiving a user ID that looks like this: `58988e75c918f5bd5804afd6`.

The database has the user name stored in the name field in the format:
`58988e75c918f5bd5804afd6 John`.

My current SQL query to fetch this record is:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE :term';
$result = db_query($sql, array(':term' => db_like($userid)));
$existingUser = $result->fetchObject();
```

With the current SQL query, even if I supply the partial user ID(58988e75c918f5bd5804), it seems to fetch the John row, which is not something I expect to happen. How to fix the query so that it exactly matches the user ID containing John?

Expected result: No records to be retrieved since the user id did not match exactly.

Update: I fetch the records and then do a substring replace to update the record in the Drupal table.

Note: Feel free to modify the sql query to get the expected result, neednt use LIKE

Comment: You are executing a select. How can it change the data?

Comment: rephrased the question

Comment: what you expect to happen? what result you expect to happen?

Comment: Expected result: No records are retrieved since the user id did not match exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a space in your like term:
[Include space in mysql like search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228924/include-space-in-mysql-like-search)

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE ":term "';
$result = db_query($sql, array(':term' => db_like($userid)));
$existingUser = $result->fetchObject();
```

Better validate the string size with PHP and then perform mysql like. As you are using same encryption style you will get same number of characters encrypted so.

Comment: But don't you need a `%` after the space?